# Python Oracle, inserting None error

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

I'm getting an error when inserting None values into oracle in the following way:

```
    host = ('value1', 'value2', None, None)
    sql_insert = "INSERT INTO sm9_data_hostname (field1, field2, field3, field4) VALUES ( :1, :2, :3, :4)"
    conn_link.execute(sql_insert, host)
    connection.commit()
```

The error is:
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number

The insert works if I use 'Null' instead of None.
I can't see what's wrong with this query as the parameters should replace the none with a Null. Or is this the wrong assumption?

Thanks,
Isaac

Comment: Have you attempted using named placeholders? e.g. `:field1`, and passing as a dictionary?

Comment: I haven't, but will try now and see if that works, thanks

Comment: That seems to have done the trick, thanks!

Comment: I've posted it up as an answer for prosperity then!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no experience at all with `cx_Oracle` but I would suggest you try using named placeholders as an alternative.  Such as the following

```
conn_link.execute(
    "INSERT INTO sm9_data_hostname (field1, field2, field3, field4) "
    "VALUES (:field1, :field2, :field3, :field4)",
    dict(field1="value1", field2="value2", field3=None, field4=None)
)
```